# Is a Radon measure always positive on non-empty open sets? The same question about the Haar measure.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

A measure is locally finite if it is finite on all compact sets from the underlying $\sigma$-algebra.

A measure is regular if every measurable set $A\in\Sigma$ can be approximated from above by open measurable sets:
$$
 \mu(A)\,=\,\operatorname{inf}\,\left\{\,\mu(O)\;\Big{|}\;A\subseteq O\;,\;\;O\in\Sigma\,,\;\,O\;\,\mbox{open}   \,\right\}\;\;,\;\;
 $$
and from below by compact measurable sets:
$$
 \mu(A)\,=\,\operatorname{sup}\,\left\{\,\mu(C)\;\Big{|}\;C\subseteq A\,,\;\,C\in\Sigma\,,\;\,C\;\,\mbox{compact}\,\right\}\;\;.
 $$

A Radon measure is a Borel measure that is introduced on the Borel algebra of a Hausdorff topological space, and is regular and locally finite.

Question 1: $\;\;$is a non-zero Radon measure always positive on non-empty open sets?

Question 2: $\;\;$the same for a non-zero Haar measure

Comment: you should specify that $\mu$ be non-zero (otherwise the answer is trivially no)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking something trivial, the answer is no. Look at the "restriction" of Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\Bbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$, by which I mean $\mu(E):= \lambda(E\cap [0,1])$. Then, $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\Bbb{R}$, hence is regular, but the open set $(10,11)$ has measure $0$ with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you. 

And the Haar measure?

Comment: @Michael_1812 I actually don't know much about Haar measures, so I'm not the right person to ask lol (if you want, update your question, and maybe someone else can answer)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you should require $\mu \ne 0$. But even then, there are trivial counterexamples.

For example, let $U$ be a non-empty subset of any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ and $x \notin U$. Then consider the Dirac measure $\delta_x$, which is Radon, and note that $\delta_x(U) = 0.$

Comment: Yes, that's an eloquent counter-example. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please answer my question also for the Haar measure?

Comment: @Michael_1812 For the Haar measure the assertion is true, there is no counterexample.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know a simple proof or a reference?

Comment: @Michael_1812 It is in Folland's book "Real analysis" in the chapter about Haar measure.

Answer (score 0):

I deeply thank the colleagues who answered my question about the Radon measure.

I think I now can answer the question about the Haar measure.

Suppose there is a nonempty open set $U$ such that $\mu(U)=0$. Any measurable set $C\in\Sigma$ can be covered by left translates of $U$, the measure of each such translate being $\mu(U)=0$ by the invariance of the Haar measure. Specifically, for a compact $C$, this cover contains a finite subcover, wherefrom we observe that $\mu(C)=0$ for any measurable compact $C$.

At the same time, by inner regularity of $\mu$, any measurable set $A\in\Sigma$ can be approximated from below by compact measurable sets. If all of them are of zero measure, then $\mu(A) =0$ for any $A\in\Sigma$. So $\mu$ is a zero measure, which contradicts the initial assumption.